# Access the `draggable` attribute with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, draggable

So the question is : How can you do that ? I want to change the `draggable` attribute to `"false"` so the element that was previously draggable will lose this property.

I will give you a div so you will have something to start with :

```
     <div id="div1"  draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event) "onDblClick="edit('div1')">
     </div>
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
document.getElementById('div1').setAttribute('draggable', false);
```

**OR**

```
var elem = document.getElementById('div1');
elem.setAttribute('draggable', false);
```

If you want the attribute totally gone use;

```
elem.removeAttribute('dragable');
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm a little late to the party, but is there a reason why we wouldn't just want to write something like this?

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.draggable = false;
```

Seems to apply the attribute fine for me.

Answer (score 5):

There is many ways, if you use `jQuery`:

```
    $('#div1').attr('dragabble'); //returns with the value of attribute
    $('#div1').attr('dragabble','false'); //sets the attribute to false
```

Native JS:

```
    document.getElementById('div1').getAttribute('draggable'); //returns the value of attr
    document.getElementById('div1').setAttribute('draggable', 'false'); //set the value of attr
```

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use jquery-ui draggable component to acheive ur required functionality..
or if u have jquery library in ur Dev environment u can use the following code

> $("#div1").attr('draggable',false);

or using javascript we can do it as follows

> document.getElementById('div1').setAttribute('draggable', 'false');

Answer (score 2):

After set the attribute `draggable` to `true`, you mostly often want to handle `dragstart` event. To do that in native JS:

```
elem.addEventListener('dragstart', ev => {
  // dragstart handlings here
  }, false)
```